# I'm looking for a good example of an integration test using Java or C# code

Tags: integration-testing

There are untold number of unit test examples, but can you provide here, or provide a link to a good example of an integration test that isn't just a metaphor? I prefer a JUnit example, but that isn't necessarily a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Providing an example of an integration test is not soooo useful. A integration test is a test that tests multiple components together to see if they work together as expected.

Imagine you have written a lexer and a parser and would like to know if the work together properly. You might do it like this:

```
@Test
public void emptyContent() throws Exception {
    assertParsable("");
}

@Test
public void complexExpression() throws Exception {
    assertParsable("a + b - (a * b)");
}

@Test
public void missingClosingBrace() throws Exception {
    assertUnparsable("(a * b");
}

private void assertParsable(String input) throws Exception {
    assertFalse(parse(input).hasErrors());
}

private void assertParsable(String input) throws Exception {
    assertTrue(parse(input).hasErrors());
}

private ParseResult parse(String input) {
    return new Parser(new Lexer(input)).parse();
}
```

**Edit:**

Personally I prefer to distinguish between fast and slow tests. It doesn't matter that much (at least for me) if I do test some components in isolation or together ... what matters is, that my tests are fast. If I test to many components together the tests are not fast, of course. This depends of what you try to achieve with the tests (I use them for writing tests before/during development and as regression suite ... I don't [have to] use them to show that my implementation matches a requirement document or something like that).

Comment: I have to disagree. Especially for integration tests, speed does not matter to me. It helps to diagnose bottlenecks maybe, but load testing should be doing the majority of that job. It may very well be that the operation I'm performing is actually supposed to take a "long time". What I really want is to find an integration test for a demo or existing application that shows how a process is being tested.

Comment: What do you think the test I provided is missing? It tests the integration of same classes, what an integration test is intended for, and I used such tests in a real project (== existing application). I think you have to define what you mean with "shows how a process is being tested".